Execution timing of Autofac OnActivated (Z.EntityFramework.Plus)
I use Autofac to replace ASP.NET default DI container.
I create a db filters with Z.EntityFramework.Plus;.
I need to apply these filters, when DbContext was Activated.

At first I use .NET 6 everything was queit right.
The program will first go to the IAsyncAuthorizationFilter, gets the user's identifier (OrgCode), and then execute the code in OnActivated only where the DbContext is used.
But when I upgraded to .NET 8, the program executes all OnActivated before it even gets to the IAsyncAuthorizationFilter.
NEED HELP,THX~ :D
I'm trying to remove the DbContext injected through the constructor in the filter, but it still first go to OnActivated.
I'd like to possibly register and run OnActivated when I actually use the DbContext, or use some sort of decorator to do that!

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
